# Is it legitimate to solve $ y'(t) = [y(t)]^{2/3} $ by dividing both parts with $ [y(t)]^{2/3} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solutions of:

$$
y'(t) = [y(t)]^{2/3} , y(0) = 0 
$$

WolframAlpha solves this problem by dividing both parts with  $ [y(t)]^{2/3}  $. However how come can it be legitimate since we are dividing both parts with 0 (when $t=0$)? Also I would like to ask what is the best way to solve this kind of differential equations?

Comment: With differential equations, the best way is often to suppose it works, find a solution, then show what you've done is legitimate. Indeed here, we must be carefull not to divide by 0 and it's very important to be carefull about that

Comment: Actually, this ODE with initial value $y(0)=0$  has a unique solution $y(t)=0$ for every $t\geq 0$.

Comment: @CTNT: Actually, that particular solution is not unique. You can compose solutions that branch off from a segment that is constant $0$.

Comment: @LutzL Can you give an example for this case? I'm really interested!

Comment: @CTNT: Put it in my answer. You should have seen in your ODE course the standard example for the difference between Peano and Picard-Lindelöf, $y'=\sqrt{|y|}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the argument more concrete for especially this case:

For $y(t_0)\ne 0$ there is a neighborhood where the differential equation is continuously differentiable and thus a locally unique solution exists. And since in this neighborhood division by zero is not a problem, you can use the separation method to find the solutions.
$$
\frac13 y(t)^{1/3-1}y'(t)=\frac13\implies y(t)^{1/3}=\frac13t+C\implies 
y(t)=\left(\frac13t+C\right)^3
$$
And for any initial value problem in the positive-y half-plane this solution is unique in the positive-y half-plane.

For solutions starting in $y(0)=0$, one can for any $t_0>0$ construct a solution that is zero on $[0,t_0]$ and continues as $y(t)=\left(\frac13(t-t_0)\right)^3$.

Comment: Good point! I missed the non-locally Lipschitz property.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I would like to ask one last thing: I am still playing with WolframAlpha, and checked if its answer would be consistent if I put $y^{4/3}$ to the RHS, for the same initial condition, but it did not produce any answers. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: I get no answer at all. With exponent $4/3$ the right side is locally Lipschitz, solutions are unique, however with a pole in finite time for all non-zero initial conditions, like with the standard example $y'=y^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Often when solving differential equations, we perform divisions that look suspect. But at the end, we look at the solution and if necessary call on a theorem about the uniqueness of solutions to ODEs to make sure it is a good solution across the entire domain we are interested in.

So yes, by all means, divide both sides by $y^{2/3}$ here, integrate, solve for $y = y(t)$ and then as a check, make sure the solution you found does satisfy the original equation and initial condition. In that case, you can forget that in its derivation, we performed a potentially 'illegal' step. We can forget about that because we now have a new logical argument that the solution we have found works and the crutch we used to get there can be thrown away.

Comment: So for this question, can we say that $y(x)=x^3/27$ is the only solution? (The one obtained by doing the division.)

Comment: Yes, that is the unique solution to the initial value problem.